# Android-Activity & Fragment not getting instance after some time of Background ideal time of Application

Tags: android, android-activity, instance

Case : 1

> When I am using 5 to 6 application with my Application running in
>   Background. After that when I tap to My Application it comes
>   foreground and not getting proper instances.

Due to that my Code is not working written in onResume method.
How can I manage the instances before and after it kills by the Android OS it self?

Null pointer Exception is created in OnResume() method is called in Activity Life Cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your application is put in background, ie. by pressing Home screen then Android might more likely kill your app process to reclaim its resources (mostly memory) - this is more probable if you switch to several other applications. When your app process is killed - then all the instances (also static ones) are killed too.

When your app is being closed - ie. you pressed Home button - android will allow you to save its state inside ie. Activity life cycle methods. When you are showing your app back, android will call life cycle methods in various components which will allow you to recreate instance state from before app was killed. This is a large topic, you can read more here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Comment: ya I know about the Activity Life cycle but I want to know How can I save the each instance because after App is restarting from Background It will not exist and return me null pointer exception.

Comment: Ie. inside Activity.onSaveInstanceState, or keep all data in sqlite

Comment: If I am using Activity.this as a my Context and many more ArrayList than It wouldn't be possible to save all their states and instance to save in onSaveInstanceState method.